# Dynamic fields in Django Admin

Tags: django, forms, dynamic, admin

I want to have additional fields regarding value of one field. Therefor I build a custom admin form to add some new fields.

Related to the blogpost of jacobian [1](http://jacobian.org/writing/dynamic-form-generation/) this is what I came up with:

```
class ProductAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Product

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ProductAdminForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['foo'] = forms.IntegerField(label="foo")

class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = ProductAdminForm

admin.site.register(Product, ProductAdmin)
```

But the additional field 'foo' does not show up in the admin. If I add the field like this, all works fine but is not as dynamic as required, to add the fields regarding the value of another field of the model

```
class ProductAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):

    foo = forms.IntegerField(label="foo")

    class Meta:
        model = Product

class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = ProductAdminForm

admin.site.register(Product, ProductAdmin)
```

So is there any initialize method that i have to trigger again to make the new field working? Or is there any other attempt?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Here is a solution to the problem. Thanks to koniiiik i tried to solve this by extending the *get_fieldsets* method

```
class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_fieldsets(self, request, obj=None):
        fieldsets = super(ProductAdmin, self).get_fieldsets(request, obj)
        fieldsets[0][1]['fields'] += ['foo'] 
        return fieldsets
```

If you use multiple fieldsets be sure to add the to the right fieldset by using the appropriate index.

Comment: `Unknown field(s) (foo) specified for GlobalLabel. Check fields/fieldsets/exclude attributes of class GlobalLabelAdmin.` I am getting this error, I dunno why... can you please help me out ?

Comment: @bhushya: were you able to figure this out? I also can't get it to work in django 1.9.3, eg: `django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (dynamicfield1, dynamicfield2) specified for MyModel`

Comment: @tehfink it seems you have not defined field in your model.. can you please post your model structure on pastebin.com and share link?

Comment: @ bhushya: you're correct; the fields (dynamicfield1, etc.) are not defined on my model. Like in the original question, I want to add fields dynamically in a `ModelForm`, and the `get_fieldsets` override mentioned above doesn't seem to work in Django 1.9.3

Comment: @bhushya: i found a potential solution for Django 1.9.3, posted below

Answer (score 15):

The accepted answer above worked in older versions of django, and that's how I was doing it.  This has now broken in later django versions (I am on 1.68 at the moment, but even that is old now).

The reason it is now broken is because any fields within fieldsets you return from `ModelAdmin.get_fieldsets()` are ultimately passed as the `fields=parameter` to `modelform_factory()`, which will give you an error because the fields on your list do not exist (and will not exist until your form is instantiated and its `__init__` is called).

In order to fix this, we must override `ModelAdmin.get_form()` and supply a list of fields that does not include any extra fields that will be added later.  The default behavior of `get_form` is to call `get_fieldsets()` for this information, and we must prevent that from happening:

```
# CHOOSE ONE
# newer versions of django use this
from django.contrib.admin.utils import flatten_fieldsets
# if above does not work, use this
from django.contrib.admin.util import flatten_fieldsets

class MyModelForm(ModelForm):
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
      super(MyModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
      # add your dynamic fields here..
      for fieldname in ('foo', 'bar', 'baz',):
          self.fields[fieldname] = form.CharField()

class MyAdmin(ModelAdmin): 
   form = MyModelForm

    fieldsets = [
       # here you put the list of fieldsets you want displayed.. only
       # including the ones that are not dynamic
    ]

    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        # By passing 'fields', we prevent ModelAdmin.get_form from
        # looking up the fields itself by calling self.get_fieldsets()
        # If you do not do this you will get an error from 
        # modelform_factory complaining about non-existent fields.

        # use this line only for django before 1.9 (but after 1.5??)
        kwargs['fields'] =  flatten_fieldsets(self.declared_fieldsets)
        # use this line only for django 1.9 and later 
        kwargs['fields'] =  flatten_fieldsets(self.fieldsets)

        return super(MyAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)

    def get_fieldsets(self, request, obj=None):
        fieldsets = super(MyAdmin, self).get_fieldsets(request, obj)

        newfieldsets = list(fieldsets)
        fields = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
        newfieldsets.append(['Dynamic Fields', { 'fields': fields }])

        return newfieldsets
```

Comment: Unfortunately, `ModelAdmin.declared_fieldsets` [has been removed](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/internals/deprecation/) in Django 1.9

Comment: Hmm.. well I guess that when I upgrade my servers to 1.9 I'm going to have some work to do ;)  But luckily I have replicated most of the admin functionality elsewhere in my application...

Comment: Also `django.contrib.admin.util` is now `django.contrib.admin.utils`

Comment: Thanks, does my answer still work otherwise?  If so I'll correct it.

Comment: Hey what about django 2.5. I have some problems with **kwargs['fields'] =  flatten_fieldsets(self.fieldsets)**  
flatten_fieldsets
    for name, opts in fieldsets:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Comment: Maybe you don't have `fieldsets` configured for your form?  I'm on django 1.11 at the moment, I just finished upgrading to python 3 a couple of weeks ago so that I can go to django 2.x in the next few weeks.  So if you can't figure it out, soon I will update my answer for django 2....

Comment: just update the line to `kwargs['fields'] =  flatten_fieldsets(self.fieldsets or [])`. The error happens if one hasn't declared the fieldsets in the class

Comment: Great answer. Note that `self.fields[fieldname] = form.CharField()` should be `self.fields[fieldname] = forms.CharField()`.

Answer (score 9):

Maybe I am a bit late... However, I am using Django 3.0 and also wanted to dynamically ad some custom fields to the form, depending on the request.

I end up with a solution similar to the one described by @tehfink combined with @little_birdie.

However, just updating `self.form.declared_fields` as suggested didn't help. The result of this procedure is, that the list of custom fields defined in `self.form.declared_fields` always grows from request to request.

I solved this by initialising this dictionary first:

```
class ModelAdminGetCustomFieldsMixin(object):
    def get_fields(self, request, obj=None):
        fields = super().get_fields(request, obj=None)
        self.form.declared_fields = {}
        if obj:
            for custom_attribute in custom_attribute_list:
                self.form.declared_fields.update({custom_attribute.name: custom_attribute.field})
        return fields
```

where `custom_attribute.field` is a form field instance.

Additionally, it was required to define a ModelForm, wherein during initialisation the custom fields have been added dynamically as well:

```
class SomeModelForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for custom_attribute in custom_attribute_list:
            self.fields[custom_attribute.name] = custom_attribute.field
```

and use this ModelForm in the ModelAdmin.

Afterwards, the newly defined attributes can be used in, e.g., a fieldset.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the Django 3.0 update, I'm kinda new in the framework. How did you implement the first class ModelAdminGetCustomFieldsMixin with SomeModelForm. I wish to show in Django admin this dynamic form based on the choice in a dropdown menu, that is being selected in the same model that will use this dynamic form

Comment: Hi Francisco, it is vice versa: `SomeModelForm` is used in the `ModelAdmin` as `form` and the `ModelAdminGetCustomFieldsMixin` is a mixin, which needs to be given as an additional class to inherit from, e.g., `SomeModelAdmin(ModelAdminGetCustomFieldsMixin, ModelAdmin)`. 
The page itself is static. The form will not change dynamically. You need either a page reload in order to change the form or a bunch of js.

Answer (score 7):

This works for adding dynamic fields in Django 1.9.3, using just a ModelAdmin class (no ModelForm) and by overriding `get_fields`. I don't know yet how robust it is:

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    fields = [('title','status', ), 'description', 'contact_person',]
    exclude = ['material']

    def get_fields(self, request, obj=None):
        gf = super(MyModelAdmin, self).get_fields(request, obj)

        new_dynamic_fields = [
            ('test1', forms.CharField()),
            ('test2', forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(MyModel.objects.all(), widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)),
        ]

        #without updating get_fields, the admin form will display w/o any new fields
        #without updating base_fields or declared_fields, django will throw an error: django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (test) specified for MyModel. Check fields/fieldsets/exclude attributes of class MyModelAdmin.

        for f in new_dynamic_fields:
            #`gf.append(f[0])` results in multiple instances of the new fields
            gf = gf + [f[0]]
            #updating base_fields seems to have the same effect
            self.form.declared_fields.update({f[0]:f[1]})
        return gf
```

Answer (score 5):

While Jacob's post might work all right for regular `ModelForm`s (even though it's more than a year and a half old), the admin is a somewhat different matter.

All the declarative way of defining models, forms ModelAdmins and whatnot makes heavy use of metaclasses and class introspection. Same with the admin – when you tell a `ModelAdmin` to use a specific form istead of creating a default one, it introspects the *class*. It gets the list of fields and other stuff from the class itself without instantiating it.

Your custom class, however, does not define the extra form field at class level, instead it dynamically adds one *after* it has been instantiated – that's too late for the `ModelAdmin` to recognize this change.

One way to go about your problem might be to subclass `ModelAdmin` and override its `get_fieldsets` method to actually instantiate the `ModelForm` class and get the list of fields from the instance instead of the class. You'll have to keep in mind, though, that this might be somewhat slower than the default implementation.

Answer (score 5):

You can create dynamic fields and fieldset using the form meta class. Sample code is given below. Add the loop logic as per you requirements.

```
class CustomAdminFormMetaClass(ModelFormMetaclass):
    """
    Metaclass for custom admin form with dynamic field
    """
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        for field in get_dynamic_fields: #add logic to get the fields
            attrs[field] = forms.CharField(max_length=30) #add logic to the form field
        return super(CustomAdminFormMetaClass, cls).__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)


class CustomAdminForm(six.with_metaclass(CustomAdminFormMetaClass, forms.ModelForm)):
    """
    Custom admin form
    """

    class Meta:
        model = ModelName
        fields = "__all__" 


class CustomAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    """
    Custom admin 
    """

    fieldsets = None
    form = CustomAdminForm

    def get_fieldsets(self, request, obj=None):
        """
        Different fieldset for the admin form
        """
        self.fieldsets = self.dynamic_fieldset(). #add logic to add the dynamic fieldset with fields
        return super(CustomAdmin, self).get_fieldsets(request, obj)

    def dynamic_fieldset(self):
        """
        get the dynamic field sets
        """
        fieldsets = []
        for group in get_field_set_groups: #logic to get the field set group
            fields = []
            for field in get_group_fields: #logic to get the group fields
                fields.append(field)

            fieldset_values = {"fields": tuple(fields), "classes": ['collapse']}
            fieldsets.append((group, fieldset_values))

        fieldsets = tuple(fieldsets)

        return fieldsets
```

Answer (score 3):

Stephan's answer is elegant, but when I used in in dj1.6 it required the field to be a tuple.
The complete solution looked like this:

```
class ProductForm(ModelForm):
    foo = CharField(label='foo')


class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = ProductForm
    def get_fieldsets(self, request, obj=None):
        fieldsets = super(ProductAdmin, self).get_fieldsets(request, obj)
        fieldsets[0][1]['fields'] += ('foo', ) 
        return fieldsets
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure why that's not working, but could a possible workaround be to define the field statically (on the form) and then override it in the `__init__`?

Answer (score 0):

I for a long time could not solve a problem with dynamic addition of fields.
The solution "little_birdie" really works. Thank you Birdie))
The only nuance is:
"Self.declared_fieldsets" should be replaced with "self.fieldsets".

```
#kwargs['fields'] =  flatten_fieldsets(self.declared_fieldsets)
kwargs['fields'] =  flatten_fieldsets(self.fieldsets)
```

I used version 1.10. Perhaps something has changed.

If someone finds an even simpler and elegant solution, show here.

Thanks to all )))