# Django Admin Customization (Change list display by the user)

Tags: javascript, python, django, overriding, admin

At Django Admin, we can use "list_display" to choose which column to show.

I want to customize Django admin so that we can decide which column to show dynamically (Not using "list_display) I want the user to be able to use something like a checkbox. Again, not by changing Python codes.

I tried the following but it seems nothing to do with the display of listing.

[Dynamic fields in Django Admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8007095/dynamic-fields-in-django-admin)

It seems I need to override/extend some Django template using JavaScript but I am not so sure.

Any comment would be greatly appreciated. (I much prefer to implement it in admin rather than outside of admin, though.)

Many thanks,

Comment: For altering which fields are displayed dynamically, you would implement this by overriding the get_fields or get_fieldsets methods inside the admin.py manager (like the post you linked). If you would like to change the fields type (square checkbox to radio-button style) then you would need to override the fields widget with a django widget or a custom created widget. This would be done by using formfield_overrides

Comment: Thanks so much. When I tried the link I posted it changes only the other screen(the one you can see when you click the specific record) (not the list display). Can you tell me why?  I will dig in more though. Thanks again.

Comment: Also, take a look at django proxy models. They can accomplish what you need because they rely on the same db table but can implement different logic (so different admin's list_display fields too). It's easier in my opinion, you can hide or show the models in the admin interface only for a certain kind of user just with django's built in permissions at that point. Much more safe and straightforward.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/models/#proxy-models

Comment: My apologies, I misread the question with my above comment! You are correct, the get_fieldsets method will only override the fields displayed when adding a new object or modifying an existing one. What you are looking to override is the `get_list_display()` method. This will allow you to control the columns you show prior to editing. You can read more about it here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display

Comment: Thanks so much to both of you. @plum 0, it works quite well. :) To Miles Davis, I will try out what you told me. All the best in 2021! :)